# Editing A Table In MVC using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, inline-editing

I am very new to MVC and coding.  I have a table that I created in using MVC, but I am wanting to hook up JavaScript to enable inline editing and post back to the database.  I think I have been watching too many tutorials, that I am now confused on how to even execute this.  Is there anyone out there who could give me a launch in the right direction as to how to begin connecting JavaScript so that I can accomplish inline editing.

Comment: Far too broad (there numerous possible approaches to solve this). Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) for one possible approach - a popup form to edit the selected row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolved my question.  This is for anyone who is wanting to know how to do inline editing of a table that you created using html.

Here is my code for the function I created once you clicked on Edit:

```
function editThis(element) {
var customerID = $(element).closest('tr').find('.customer-stored-   id').attr('data-value');
GetByID("Home/Edit", customerID, replaceCustomerRow, element);
```

}

This function replaces the row

```
function replaceCustomerRow(result, element) {
$(element).closest('tr').replaceWith(result);
```

}

This function will get the ID

```
function GetByID(url, id, callback, param1) {

$.ajax({
    url: "../../" + url + "/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        if (callback != null && callback != undefined) {
            callback(result, param1);
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        if (result.responseText != '') {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }
        else {
            alert("An error occurred while processing results.  Please consult an administrator.");
        }
    }
})
```

}

Then you would just write your code for the controller.  Simple enough, but it works.